# Beamer: alert and math color

Tags: beamer, math-mode, color

I'm having some trouble changing the colors of parts of an equation in Beamer, with "math text" being set. The following MWE demonstrates the example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{color}
\setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=blue}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame}
    $x \alert{\cong} y \alert{=} z$ \\
    $x \textcolor{green}{\cong} y \textcolor{green}{=} z$ \\
    $x {\setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=green}{\cong}} y {\setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=green}{=}} z$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I would expect both symbols in the first and second line to get colored. However, for some reason, `\cong` is not colored, but `=` is. Is there some way to make coloring work reliably with all math symbols?

I found another Stackexchange question ([Changed all math text to red in beamer, now I can't make some math text black](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87812/changed-all-math-text-to-red-in-beamer-now-i-cant-make-some-math-text-black)) where people suggested the code I used in the third line - which, confusingly, works for `\cong`, but not for `=`.

For now, I replaced `\cong` by `\stackrel{\sim}{=}`, but really that's just a work-around, and if this ever happens with a symbol I cannot reconstruct otherwise, I'll be in trouble.

Comment: I would not use `\textcolor` inside math, it messes up the spacing, see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261480/36296 for an alternative. However this also has your problem with `\cong`.

Comment: But have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/234218/36296 It looks like this could solve your problem

Comment: That may help, though it doesn't fix `alert`. I'd also need to figure out the actual color beamer is using here. Is there a macro to fetch that?

Comment: Okay, so the following works: `\newcommand<>\mathalert[1]{{\only#2{\usebeamercolor{alerted text}\color{fg}\setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=fg}}#1}}%`. Thanks!